# sort a struct array by attribute value

Tags: c, sorting, attributes, struct

Ive got a task in C to sort a struct by using qsort

```
struct user {
    enum SEX{m, f} sex;
    char name[32];
    char phonenr[32];

};
typedef struct user User;
```

the users will be stored in a array of 25 elements

but how do i sort them on something like name ?

Comment: Do you know how to use qsort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case it's pretty easy, since `strcmp` works nicely with `qsort`.  Try:

```
int compareUser(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const User *u1 = v1;
    const User *u2 = v2;
    return strcmp(u1->name, u2->name);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
qsort(array, 25, sizeof(User), compareUser);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Edited to shut up warnings, being strictly correct is always a good idea.