# Sorting a C char array based on contents of another array containing the indexes

Tags: c

I currently have 2 arrays:

```
char A = {"Hello", "Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4"}
int B = {3, 2, 0, 1};
```

Each indexes placement in the `B` array corresponds to the same index placement in the messages array. E.g
`"Hello"` needs to be in place 3, `"Hello2"` needs to be in place 2, `"Hello3"` needs to be in place 0 and `"Hello4"` needs to be in place 1.

Desired output:

```
char aSorted = {"Hello3", "Hello4", "Hello2", "Hello"};
```

Therefore, I need a sorting algorithm that can sort `A` based on `B`. I'm really struggling to wrap my head around this and was wondering if anyone could give me a solution to do this  in C. Keep in mind that my A and B arrays could potentially have 256000 values each so it should be optimal. Thanks.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: That's not really a question of sorting, it's about filling a new array based on the data you have. It should be straightforward.

Comment: Allocate a fresh array `F`, traverse `B` with integer `i`, `aSorted[B[i]] = A[i]`.

Comment: That comment should have been an answer.

Comment: The code shown does not compile. `char A` does not define an array, nor do `int B` or `char aSorted`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(argc,argv)
const char** argv;
{
        char chararray[4]={'H','I','J','K'};
        int indexarray[4]={3,2,0,1};
        char newchararray[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                newchararray[i]=chararray[indexarray[i]];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                printf("%c ",newchararray[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        return 0;
}
```

But one more thing, How are you putting strings like that in a char array?
My compiler, `cc` to be more specific, gives

```
error: excess elements in char array initializer
  char chararray[4]={"H","I","J","K"};
                         ^
```

Comment: An array of 4 C strings is `char *array[4]` and you print strings with the `"%s"` format.

Comment: But that's not what Shaun is doing. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, that's probably a typo in the original question. (The question does not show a lot of effort.) And I misunderstood your last question as more or less literal, but it was addressed at OP. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yep very true :) Maybe, the question is different and he interpreted it differently. That happens if one is exhausted too much. If we look at the strings carefully, the question maybe adjust them as per the number they contain, like for example `hello2` in the second position and so on. Anyways, thanks :)

Comment: But, one thing is for sure, my algorithm will yield horrible performance, if the array is as large as he says. You got any better ideas bro?

Comment: Why do you think the performance is horrid? The data is arbitrary and you must fill in every  slot of the new array, so you can't be better than O(n). You could only get better if you knew that you only need to swap very few itams, but we don't have that information. Perhaps you are confusing this with the complexity of many sorting algorithms, which is O(n log(n)). O(log(n)) is the complexity of binary search, but that doesn't have to visit every item.

Answer (score 0):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2908221/710162):

Create a struct with both arrays:

```
struct myText {
    char A;
    int B;

};
typedef struct myText MyText;
```

Create the comparator:

```
int compareMyText(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const MyText *u1 = v1;
    const MyText *u2 = v2;
    return u1->B < u2->B;
}
```

Call qsort:

```
qsort(array, 25, sizeof(myText), compareMyText);
```

Full working code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct myText
{
    char *A;
    int B;
};
typedef struct myText MyText;


int compareMyText (const void *v1, const void *v2) {
     const MyText *u1 = v1;
     const MyText *u2 = v2;
     return u1->B < u2->B;
}

int main () {
    MyText array[4];
    array[0].A = "Hello";
    array[0].B = 3;
    array[1].A = "Hello2";
    array[1].B = 2;
    array[2].A = "Hello3";
    array[2].B = 0;
    array[3].A = "Hello4";
    array[3].B = 1;

    qsort (array, 4, sizeof (MyText), compareMyText);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf ("%s - %d\n", array[i].A, array[i].B);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ISO C forbids nested functions.

Comment: @EdHeal: Because `qsort()` expects this. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: You can just cast the parameter - And thus avoiding void pointers except in the cast

Comment: @EdHeal: Using `int(*)(const void*, const void*)` as type for the compare function is a must. And else I do not see any void-pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution.....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *A[] = {"Hello", "Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4"};//declare A as char pointer
  int B[] = {3, 2, 0, 1};
  #define SIZE (sizeof B / sizeof (int)) //make code extensible;
                          //sizeof(int array)->"B" divided by sizeof(int)
  char *C[SIZE];           

  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE;i++){
    C[i] = A[B[i]]; //array C stores the sorted result
}

/* To print the result

  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE;i++){
    printf("%s ",C[i]);
  }
  putchar('\n');   
*/

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `#define SIZE sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0])` should better be `#define SIZE(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))`. Then use it like `SIZE(B)`.